# C#Web сервис подключение

Tags: c#

Вопрос такой. У меня есть класс веб службы:

```
public class SomeService : WebService
{
    public const string XmlNS = "http://asmx.bubu.ru/";
    public static List<AppDomain> DomainList;
    public static readonly global::log4net.ILog LogInstance;
    public static Remote remoteProxy;
    public static LoginSettings userSettings;

    public SomeService();
}
```

Я хочу создать новый asmx файл описателя веб-службы, который будет работать на основании этого вышеуказанного класса веб-службы.

Answer (score 0):

Просите, заработался, - просто создать веб службы класс как наследник от класса SomeService, и использовать все его методы